# How to get values that are >= 25%, 50%, 75% of a list from a column using SQL

Tags: sql, select, where-clause, clickhouse

My table has a single column called `Speed` (integer), and I need to select values that are greater than 25%, 50%,... values in that list.

Sample data:

```
+-------+
| Speed |
+-------+
|     1 |
|     2 |
|     3 |
|     4 |
|     5 |
|     6 |
|     7 |
|     8 |
|     9 |
|    10 |
+-------+
```

Desired output:

```
+--------+
| OUTPUT |
+--------+
|      3 |
|      5 |
|      8 |
+--------+
```

Explain:

- 3 >= 25% numbers in the list
- 5 >= 50% numbers in the list
- 8 >= 75% numbers in the list

I think that I should sort the data, and do something like:

```
SELECT speed 
FROM my_table
WHERE speed IN (ROUND(0.25 * <total_row>), ROUND(0.50 * <total_row>),..)
```

but I don't know how to get that `<total_row>` reference. If I could just `SELECT COUNT(speed) AS total_row`, and use that later, that would be great.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Clickhouse implements a very limited subset of SQL.  Do you have any other options for a database to use?

Comment: I have no idea why this question would be downvoted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
create table Speed Engine=Memory 
as select number+1 X from numbers(10);

SELECT quantilesExact(0.25, 0.5, 0.75)(X)
FROM Speed

┌─quantilesExact(0.25, 0.5, 0.75)(X)─┐
│ [3,6,8]                            │
└────────────────────────────────────┘


SELECT arrayJoin(quantilesExact(0.25, 0.5, 0.75)(X)) AS q
FROM Speed

┌─q─┐
│ 3 │
│ 6 │
│ 8 │
└───┘

SELECT arrayJoin(quantilesExact(0.25, 0.499999999999, 0.75)(X)) AS q
FROM Speed

┌─q─┐
│ 3 │
│ 5 │
│ 8 │
└───┘
```

In CH realm Join is not applicable because it's usually billions of rows.

```
create table Speed Engine=MergeTree order by X  as select number X from numbers(1000000000);

SELECT quantilesExact(0.25, 0.5, 0.75)(X)
FROM Speed

┌─quantilesExact(0.25, 0.5, 0.75)(X)─┐
│ [250000000,500000000,750000000]    │
└────────────────────────────────────┘

1 rows in set. Elapsed: 7.974 sec. Processed 1.00 billion rows,

SELECT quantiles(0.25, 0.5, 0.75)(X)
FROM Speed

┌─quantiles(0.25, 0.5, 0.75)(X)────────┐
│ [244782599,500713390.5,751014086.75] │
└──────────────────────────────────────┘

1 rows in set. Elapsed: 1.274 sec. Processed 1.00 billion rows
```

Comment: Since I'm using ClickHouse, this answer is the best match. Other answers are great for SQL in general.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit long for a comment.

Basically, to answer this question in SQL there are three approaches:

1. Window functions.
2. Correlated subqueries to calculate cumulative counts.
3. Self-join with non-equal conditions and aggregation to calculative cumulative counts.

The first is BY FAR the best approach.  But the other two can be used in databases that don't support window functions.

Alas, Clickhouse does not support:

- Window functions.
- Correlated subqueries.
- Non-equijoins.

It might have undocumented features or extensions that support one or more of this functionality.  However, the base product does not seem to support enough SQL to do this as a single query.

EDIT:

There would seem to be a way, assuming that `rowNumberInAllBlocks()` obeys the ordering specified in `order by`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             rowNumberInAllBlocks() as seqnum,
             tt.cnt
      from t cross join
           (select count(*) as cnt from t) tt
      order by speed
     ) t
where (t.seqnum <= tt.cnt * 0.25 and t.seqnum + 1 > tt.cnt * 0.25) or
      (t.seqnum <= tt.cnt * 0.50 and t.seqnum + 1 > tt.cnt * 0.50) or
      (t.seqnum <= tt.cnt * 0.75 and t.seqnum + 1 > tt.cnt * 0.75) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for a not effective but working solution, try this:

1. declare a var for max value:

   ```
   declare @maxspeed int = (select max(speed) from my_table)
   ```
2. select fro my_table relevant values:

   ```
   select speed 
   from my_table
   where speed in ((select top 1 speed 
                    from @my_table
                    where speed > 0.25 * @maxspeed),
                   (select top 1 speed 
                    from @my_table
                    where speed > 0.5 * @maxspeed),
                   (select top 1 speed 
                    from @my_table
                    where speed > 0.75 * @maxspeed))
   ```

Answer (score 0):

First you do a self join so each row is joined to all the rows with `Speed` less than or equal to the rows `Speed`.
Then cross join to the query that returns the total number of rows of the table.
Finally group by the percentage of the rows that each `Speed` is greater, rounded to the integer values of 25, 50 and 75 and get the minimum `Speed` for each group:

```
select min(t.speed) Output 
from (select count(*) total from tablename) c
cross join (
  select t.speed, count(*) counter
  from tablename t inner join tablename tt
  on tt.speed <= t.speed
  group by t.speed
) t 
where 25 * floor(floor(100.0 * t.counter / c.total) / 25) in (25, 50, 75)
group by 25 * floor(floor(100.0 * t.counter / c.total) / 25)
```

This code is tested and working for MySql, Postgresql and SQL Server.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/c7CoZVE6BHiQrxfg8zfK92/2).
Results:

```
| output |
| ------ |
| 3      |
| 5      |
| 8      |
```